# Are there other kind of primitives, other than $\int_a ^x f(t)dt +k$ ? For example for non-continuous functions.

Tags: integration, riemann-integration

The second fundamental theorem of Calculus says if a function is continuous (hence, Riemann integrable) then $\int_a ^x f(t) dt$ is a primitive of $f$. Ok this is for continuous functions.

However what happens for not necessarily continuous functions ? The first fundamental theorem of Calculus says if $f$ is Riemann integrable (i.e. not necessarily continuous) then $\int_a ^b f(t) dt = F(b) - F(a)$ where $F$ is a primitive.

Can $F$, in the context of the first fundamental theorem, be a primitive not of the form $\int_a ^x f(t) dt$ ?

Or do all the Riemann integrable functions have primitives of the form $\int_a ^x f(t) dt$ ?

Comment: If $f$ is not continuous then $F(x)=\int_a ^x f(t) dt$ could be not differentiable, or even if it is differentiable it can happen that $F' \ne f$

Comment: Then we must look for another primitive (not of the form $\int _a ^x f(t) dt$). I mean, in case $F(x) = \int _a ^x f(t) dt$ is not differentiable or $F'\neq f$

Comment: You should observe that two primitives $g, h$ of a function $f$ on an interval $I$ differ by a constant. Why? Because $(g-h) '=g' - h'=f-f=0$. And note that if $g$ is a primitive of $f$ with $f$ being Riemann integrable then $g(x) $ is nothing but $\int_a^x f(t) \, dt+g(a) $

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not all Riemann Integrable functions have primitives. Consider $f: [0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$ given by $f(x)=0, x\in[0,1/2)$ and $f(x)=1, x\in[1/2,1]$.

$f$ cannot be the derivative of a function because [derivatives satisfy the Darboux condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darboux%27s_theorem_(analysis)) and $f$ doesn't (it doesn't take on $1/2$, for example).

Now, $$f(x) = \cases{2x\sin\frac{1}{x^2}-\frac{2}{x}\cos\frac{1}{x^2} \quad\text{for } x\ne 0
\\0\quad\text{for }x=0}$$ is not continuous at $x=0$, but $$F(x) = \cases{x^2 \sin\frac{1}{x^2} \quad \text{for } x\ne 0 \\ 0\quad\text{for }x=0}$$

is a primitive of $f$.

Comment: Does your second example is an example of a case where the primitive $F$ is not of the form $\int_a ^x f(t) dt$ ? Thanks for your answer

Comment: I don't think so. One can prove that if a function is integrable and continuous at a point $x_0$ then $F'(x_0)=f(x_0)$, where $F(x)=\displaystyle\int_a^{x} f(t) dt$. It is well known a function is Riemann Integrable iff it is continuous except in a set of null measure, so we will have $F'(x)=f(x)$ almost everywhere.

Comment: Did you wanted to mean "a function is **Lebesgue Integrable** iff it is continuous except in a set of null measure" ? According to this [Mit page](https://ocw.mit.edu/ans7870/18/18.013a/textbook/HTML/chapter20/section04.html) the function equal to $1$ on the rationals and zero elsewhere is not Riemann Integrable on $[a,b]$.

Comment: @niobium That function doesn't have a set of discontinuities of null measure.